# Parsing JSON File with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to parse a JSON File I created for an app I am working on.  The JSON file looks like this:

```
{"thresholds":[
    {"heatIndex":[
        {"maxTemp":[{"red":"125","orange":"105","yellow":"90","green":"-80"}]},
        {"minTemp":[{"red":"-50","orange":"-35","yellow":"-20","green":"0"}]}
    ]},
    {"wind":[
        {"speed":[{"red":"34.8","orange":"26.1","yellow":"17.4","green":"0"}]},
        {"gust":[{"red":"50.4","orange":"39.1","yellow":"26.1","green":"0"}]}
    ]}
]}
```

I need to get my angular app to output the data for me and have been trying to follow the tutorials for http.get and I am not able to get my data out.  The basic part I need help with how to format this part of my Angular app:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in thresholds">
        {{x.thresholds}}
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- NG APP Script -->
    <script>
    var ehwo2App = angular.module('ehwo2App' , []);
    ehwo2App.controller('ehwo2Ctrl' , function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('config.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.thresholds = data;
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: $scope.thresholds = JSON.parse(data); (as data is coming string I think)  ask your friend Google before posting question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin actually you don't have to do this, angular automatically parses json for you. Try being less condescending when commenting unless you know for a fact that you're right.

Answer (score 1):

in your $http request, try changing it from:

```
 $scope.thresholds = data;
```

to

```
 $scope.thresholds = data.thresholds;
```

Comment: Thanks bro.  Still not sure about drilling down further though.  For example if I want maxTemp:red value etc...

Comment: I have a bit of a problem remebering that too.  You should be able to access the data the same way you would access a javascript object, I believe.  So the max temps would be $scope.thresholds.heatIndex.maxTemp  check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that `success` shortcut method is now deprecated, and you should use the standard `.then` methods (see the red box on [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get).

Secondly, you've not actually said *what* exactly isn't working. Try using the below code and let us know what is logged in the console.

```
ehwo2App.controller('ehwo2Ctrl' , function ($scope, $http) {

  console.log("Making GET request");

  $http.get('http://www.dev.nids.noaa.gov/~mneedham/config.json')

  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.thresholds = response.data.thresholds;
    console.log($scope.thresholds);
  })

  .catch(function(error){
    console.error("Error with GET request", e);
  });

});
```